# webstorm config es6? but can not use import/export

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I config use babel。the webstorm also config the syntax to es6。
but I only can not use import/export? why? 
the class/let can use?[image]

Comment: How did you configure it? (steps through menu)

Comment: Try import express from "../node_modules/express";

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't support ES6-style imports. You need to compile your code to run it in Node.js. Consider using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) with babel-node or require hook. Here's how to configure that in WebStorm for development: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/#using-es6-in-nodejs